# C# Format Currency From Database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm retrieving data from my MySQL database and formatting it but I want the cents to be inside a `<sup></sup>` tag. Not sure how I go about doing this. I'm using a handler with a StringBuilder to write all the HTML and then filling it into a div. I'm using **money** data type in the database.

Here is the format:

```
string.Format("{0:C}", dt.Rows[i]["itemPrice"])
```

I'm trying to write something like:

$39<sup>.99</sup>

```
$39<sup>.99</sup>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to split it like this:

```
double p =  Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i]["itemPrice"]);
var pi = (int)p;
double pr = (p - pi)*100;
string formattedPrice = string.Format("{0:C0}<sup>.{1:00}</sup>", pi,pr);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!! It worked although. Although I had to Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i]["itemPrice"]) instead of (double)